# How to Insert a QR Code in POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

Is it possible to insert a printable and scan worthy QR Code in the XSSF spreadsheet using the POI java library?

I have the code written that generates the spread sheet and java code to create the QR code but I do not know how to join them together.

Comment: If you can get the QR code image, it can be inserted in the excel sheet via POI

Comment: Are there sample code or examples of this?

Comment: Just google for it e.g.
http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/06/apache-poi-excel-insert-image.html